# The right way to verify that javax.persistence.EntityManager.remove(Object entity) actually removed the entity

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

We are converting from EJB2 to EJB3 plus JPA.

The EJB2 EntityBean's ejbremove method throws a javax.ejb.RemoveException

Whereas the Javax.Persistence.EntityManager.remove throws only an IllegalArgumentException and a TransactionRequiredException none of which speaks to whether the entity was removed or not (or so I glean from the javadocs)

So how can I verify that whatever it was that would have generated a RemoveException did not happen in the execution of the EntityManager.remove()

I suppose I could save the primary key of the object before trying to remove it and searching for it afterwards and verifying that it isn't in fact there, but that's round about and I suspect I'm simply missing something obvious.

Comment: remove() doesn't actually remove an entity. It marks it for removal. The actual removal will happen at the next flush, and the removal will only be "permanent" once the tranasction is committed. If any exception occurs, the only thing you can do is rollback the current transaction. And if there is a rollback, the removal, even if it happened, is... rollbacked.

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect.